# gperftools - profile file not dumped

Tags: profiling, ubuntu-14.04, qt-creator, gperftools

I've configured and built [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools). however, I can't seem to find the generated profile file of my program to display it.

I took the following actions:

1. Adding the `-lprofiler` linker flag to my `.pro`, building the program and the flag is added correctly at the linking stage.
   `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lprofiler`
2. Running with:
   `$ CPUPROFILE=/tmp/prof.out /path/to/executable`
3. Executing:
   `$ pprof --gv /path/to/MyExe /tmp/prof.out`

Then I get the following:

`Failed to get profile: curl -s --max-time 90 'http:///pprof/profile?seconds=30' > /home/eslam/pprof/.tmp.MyExe.1509005857.: No such file or directory.`

Anyone has a resolve on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check that your program actually links to libprofiler.so. Some OSes (e.g. AFAIK some versions of ubuntu) do not actually add .so if none of it's symbols are actually used. E.g. ldd ./yourprogram should list libprofiler.so. If this does not happen, then you should prepend something like -Wl,--no-as-needed to your linker flags.

Comment: Correct, listing the dynamic dependencies using ldd didn't yield the libprofiler.so. Using      QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--no-as-needed,-lprofiler,--as-needed. it's very important though to turn on the  --as-needed option back not to link extra dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

**`LD_PRELOAD` method without rebuild**

Besides passing `-Wl,--no-as-needed,-lprofiler,--as-needed` at build time [mentioned by Eslam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949407/gperftools-profile-file-not-dumped#comment81826459_47022660), you can also get it to work without modifying the build by passing the `LD_PRELOAD` option at runtime as:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprofiler.so CPUPROFILE=prof.out ./main.out
```

You can find `libprofiler.so` easily with `locate libprofiler.so`.

See also: [How can I profile C++ code running on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/how-can-i-profile-c-code-running-on-linux/60265409#60265409)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.